# Installation Size Enlightenment

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-netbook

Looking [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/wubi_ubuntu_on_windows_p2), why does the "Installation Size:" differ? What differs an Installation Size of 10GB to 30GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi installs a virtual disk inside your Windows partition. The installation size parameter determines how large this virtual disk image will be ; you will use this much space on your Windows drive.

I am quite a heavy user (software development, etc) and my root partition uses about 9.8GB, for guidance.